# How could db schemas, implemented by Liquibase, be extended?

Tags: java, oracle, postgresql, liquibase

We have a product that we are looking to use liquibase to implement/re-factore the db schema. This then needs to be extended at the production site level that might have differences in the schema. Site schema could be different from one another i.e. having extra site specific tables, extra columns and so on.

So how could db schemas, implemented by Liquibase, be extended at the site level? i.e. How could the Liquibase project be extended so that the site specific change sets could be implemented?

p.s. we normally have Oracle and Postgres solutions.

Comment: Are these site customizations known by you before hand or is the site adding them at any time and you're not able to anticipate them?

Comment: The sites are on different jurisdictions and naturally there are unforeseen changes that would apply only to one site and not the others. Also there are known schema differences that satisfies site specific requirements. In other word, we have a product level schema which is extend on the site level to satisfy known requirements and future changes to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what @SteveDonie said there's a another possible solution or maybe a hybrid solution.  In your source code structure you store standard code and custom code.  You then make use of the raw sql change log files that Liquibase allows you to use.

So have a folder structure something like this:

```
DbCode
      |
      |---Standard
                  |---Tables
                            |---employee.sql
                            |---sale.sql
                   |---Schemas
                              |---public.sql
      |---Site1
                  |---Tables
                            |---site1_specific_table.sql
                   |---Schemas
                              |---site1.sql
      |---Site2
                  |---Tables
                            |---site2_specific_table.sql
                   |---Schemas
                              |---site2.sql
```

In your root folder of the Standard folder place 0_Main.xml.  When you run liquibase with this file it will create a upgrade for a standard database build. However if we add in the custom site we will get a upgrade specific to the site. This will allow you to store common or what I called standard code once under the standard folder and any site specific code under the given site folder. So we place 0_Main.xml under Site1 and Site2.

C:\DbCode\Standard\0_Main.xml looks like this:

```
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <includeAll  path="C:/ProjectX/Standard/Schemas"/>
    <includeAll  path="C:/ProjectX/Standard/Tables"/>
    <includeAll  path="C:/ProjectX/Standard/ForeignKeys"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

C:\DbCode\Site1\0_Main.xml looks like this:

```
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <includeAll  path="C:/ProjectX/Standard/Schemas"/>
    <includeAll  path="C:/ProjectX/Standard/Tables"/>
    <includeAll  path="C:/ProjectX/Standard/ForeignKeys"/>

    <includeAll  path="C:/ProjectX/Site1/Schemas"/>
    <includeAll  path="C:/ProjectX/Site1/Tables"/>
    <includeAll  path="C:/ProjectX/Site1/ForeignKeys"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

C:\DbCode\Site2\0_Main.xml looks like this:

```
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <includeAll  path="C:/ProjectX/Standard/Schemas"/>
    <includeAll  path="C:/ProjectX/Standard/Tables"/>
    <includeAll  path="C:/ProjectX/Standard/ForeignKeys"/>

    <includeAll  path="C:/ProjectX/Site2/Schemas"/>
    <includeAll  path="C:/ProjectX/Site2/Tables"/>
    <includeAll  path="C:/ProjectX/Site2/ForeignKeys"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

With those configurations in place you can build code to a standard version and\or to a Site1, or Site2 version.

The includeAll tags tell liquibase to go into the given directory and get all the scripts. So by doing includeAll to the Standard folder first we get all the standard objects added to the upgrade followed by all the Site specific scripts when we call includeAll against their folders.

Comment: If it would help to have a conversation on this let me know and we can figure a way to talk. It's hard to explain all the details and advantages of this in a text post that doesn't run multiple pages. I love optimizing database builds to be logical and easy to use and jump at the chance to talk about it.

Comment: Also this assumes that all code goes through the build process. That is no one logs into a database and just deploys code off radar. IF you have code going in off radar I can't help you.

Comment: It makes perfect sense. Your solution is more appropriate for our build process. I can assure you that there isn't any code that doesn't go through the build process and this should never be the case anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Liquibase has the concept of "contexts" that can be used to describe changes that are specific to a given environment. Typically, these are used for things like a development environment, a test or staging environment, etc., but they are completely general and could be used for you different sites as well.

Here is the documentation on that: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/contexts.html